# Create Design Package - Access Denied

Tags: 2013, access-denied, sql, design, design-manager

I need to create a **design package** for a site collection,
but when I try to create it (from Design Manager), I get a

> 403 Forbidden Error

I am site collection administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **application pool account** did not have *permission on the SharePoint Config database*.
Adding the permission for the application pool user solved my problem.